# Evaluating a WHERE AND drupal 6 mysql query

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to write mysql query where i have two where clauses so the hierarchy with brackets is something like (where x and y) OR (where m and n).

```
   $value = db_query("
SELECT id, b,c 
FROM {grant_status} 
WHERE b='%s' AND b_val='%s' 
OR 
WHERE c='%s' AND c_val='%s'
", $name,'val', $name,'val');
```

This isn't evaluating and I would like to know if it is written correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you mean

```
$value = db_query("
SELECT id, b,c 
FROM {grant_status} 
WHERE (b='%s' AND b_val='%s') 
OR 
(c='%s' AND c_val='%s')
", $name,'val', $name,'val');
```

Comment: The brackets aren't necessary since AND has precedence over OR.